# How am I supposed to join these tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to make a query where the New_item table is linked to an excel file. I want the query to show all values from the New_item table whether it has a pair in other tables or not e.g. if the Artikol_tkt or the Shade doesn't exist in other tables yet.
I've tried it with left join but still doesn't appear if I enter a new item with a new Artikol_tkt.

[The relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXX6f.png)

```
SELECT
New_item.Artikol_tkt
, New_item.Shade
, Artikol.Description
, Color.MPG
, Artikol.Supplier
, Artikol.BUoM
, Artikol.Net_weight
, Price.Purchase_Price
, Supplier.Freight
, New_item.Entry_Date
FROM 
(((New_item LEFT JOIN Artikol ON New_item.Artikol_tkt = Artikol.Artikol_tkt)
 LEFT JOIN Supplier ON Artikol.Supplier = Supplier.Supplier)
 LEFT JOIN Price ON New_item.Artikol_tkt = Price.Artikol_tkt)
 LEFT JOIN Color ON New_item.Shade = Color.Shade
WHERE Color.MPG = Price.MPG 
AND New_item.Entry_Date = CDate('25/10/2022');
```

Comment: Move the Color.MPG = Price.MPG  condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result. (As it is now, that join will give regular inner join result.)

Comment: Move to which join?

Comment: The last one (LEFT JOIN Color.)

Comment: But I still need to link New_item.Shade to Color.Shade otherwise it wont choose an MPG given the shade and tge result is meaningless

Comment: Yes, but in the ON clause. (If you want LEFT JOIN, otherwise do INNER JOIN.)

Comment: I m sorry but i dont understand. Can you edit the code and send it please?

Comment: I just suggest a better name for question, like "how to join multiple tables having a corresponding pair or not".
You provided useful information IMHO

Comment: Are you using Access query designer to construct SQL?

Comment: Looks like circular referencing to me https://www.codeproject.com/articles/38655/prevent-circular-references-in-database-design. Not really understanding your data structure.